# Can daemontools (djbtools) be configured to start multiple processes as a single UNIX service?

Tags: unix, service, daemon, daemontools

If I have an application that requires two separate processes (front- and back-end) to run properly, is it possible to launch both of them from a single runscript and have daemontools supervise both of them and treat them as a single service? If so, how? Or would they need to be, by definition, two separate daemons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no: It's been a while since I've used Daemontools `svc` stuff, but as I recall it opens a pipe between the daemontools monitoring program and the daemon being spawned -- If I remember correctly that pipe closing is how it determines that the daemon "died" and needs to restart.

Since the pipe is one program to one program there would be no way to monitor the second daemon: You would need to create a separate daemontools service for it.